# Positioning a tikzfigure to be on the left of a text block

Tags: floats, positioning, wrapfigure, wrap, tikzposter

I am making a poster for my dissertation presentation and I am trying to move an image from the centre of my text block to the left side but I can't work out how to do it. I had a look in the documentation for tikzposter but couldnt see anything about moving the position of the figures. I have added an image below of what it looks like:

[image]

What I  am trying to do is just to move the Python logo to be left-justified in the box.

here is the latex code for the block and image:

```
\begin{tikzfigure}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{images/768px-Python-logo-notext.svg.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

that is being called in the main.tex using `\input{techused.tex}`
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `\minipage`, it will do exactly what you're looking for. And come back later if you have any trouble.

Comment: I added the mini page and it positioned the image to the left-hand side of the text block, although the text that follows the image gets pushed towards the right, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please post a minimal working example of what you did already (edit your first post) and sure you'll find people to help. I probably will.